# C# Windows Form html like dropdown menu

Tags: c#, forms, drop-down-menu

I am looking to create a dropdown menu in my windows form application that is similar to the dropdown menu in html i.e.  etc..

I need each entry to display text to user but store a value to be used in my app.

I am currently using a combobox but that doens't seem to let me store an associated value for each entry.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store anything in a combo box, up to and including an object instance that holds the value you need, plus the string. All you need to do is override `ToString` in the class you use as item.

```
class Item {
    public string Name = "";
    public int Value = 0;

    public Item(string name, int value) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Item item = new Item("Item no. " + i.ToString(), i);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

When you work with `comboBox1.Items` all you need to do is cast the items to `Item` and you're all set.

Answer (score 2):

A `ComboBox` does let you store as many associated values as you want - just bind it to a collection of your objects (which can as many properties as you like), and use `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember`, and `SelectedValue` properties of the `ComboBox` to designate property that will provide text to be displayed, and property that will provide value for `SelectedValue`.